# How to apply specific style to parent based on its child class in SASS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I have a nested dropdown navigation as shown below :

```
<div class="menu-list">
   <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
      <li> Hi </li>
      <li class="parent_li" data-target="#products_sidebar" data-trigger="click" data-toggle="collapse" data-placement="right">
         Sub Route
         <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id ="products_sidebar">
            <li >Sub A</li>  <!-- gets a class "active" on click -->
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The `li` for sub-route gets highlighted on click(done using `active-class` of vue router-link). **But how to highlight its parent li (`.parent_li`) ?**

I know this can be handled in JS. But i am expecting solution in SASS or CSS

Comment: Doesnt `.parent:active{}` also work?

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/6191987

Comment: You can't target an element's parent in CSS (or in SASS).

Comment: you need to specify the separate class for the parent on the active state of the list using the js